# Problems to practice programming under linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, ipc

I have started using/learning linux few days back. I am reading the book "Advanced Linux Programming". It is a very nice book but it does not contain exercises to practice.
I am not able to make problems on my own.
Can you please share a link or a book where I can get problems to practice C/C++ under Linux?

EDIT: I was looking for problems related to multithreading,interprocess communication and synchronization. 
I know C and C++. I have been working on windows and now I want to learn Linux.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn proper C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963019/how-to-learn-proper-c). There have been several questions on SO about learning. So make some queries and you will find great content. One thing, you need to write code.

Comment: Did you miss these :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qN7u1j44QTo

Comment: Did you know already how to write single-threaded, no communicating programs before? Because trying to run when you don't know how to walk is a difficult task.

Comment: Yes I know C and C++. I have been working on windows but now I want to learn Linux

Answer (score 4):

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~wjk/C++Intro/RobMillerE1.html

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Exercises/Iterations

http://www.cprogramming.com/challenge.html

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Several books have exercises at the end of each chapter. Most which have been recommended on StackOverflow do. There are also challenges and exercises online, but I think it is for the intermediates.

Btw googling ***"c++ programming exercises beginners"*** give tons of results, even the one Nader mentionned. Also check out [codechef easy section](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88403/c-exercises-for-beginners)